# How to map many to many property with automapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many, automapper

I want to map my many to objects with AutoMapper, but could not create.

I am using Entity Framework Core 3.0 version.

My entites:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAttached { get; set; }      
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

My dtos:

```
public class RolesOfUserViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAttached { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

So I have a rest endpoint to get roles of a user with `DateAttached` property from many to many table.

```
var x = await _context.Users
    .Include(role => role.UserRoles)
    .Where(user => user.userRoles.Any(s => s.RoleId == id))
    .ToListAsync();
```

I have created a map for these classes:

```
CreateMap<Role, RolesOfUserViewModel>()
    .AfterMap((source, destination) =>
    {
        foreach (var userRole in source.UserRoles)
            destination.DateAttached = userRole.DateAttached;
    });
```

But this sets wrong values, because one user may have many roles. How can I do this?

Comment: Works for me. See [this .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2G7tQZ), run this in your web browser or copy the code to VS and set a breakpoint after the mapping and inspect the results.

Comment: I noticed that your query returns a list of users, but your AutoMapper configuration creates a map from role, not user. Is this deliberate?